# Deleting a table in Big Query via Node.js API, and getting ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, bash, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client, enoent

I realise this may be a dumb question, so thank you for taking the time to read (and hopefully answer) it. I'm v new to both Javascript and node, so please assume I know v little jargon.

I'm trying to delete a Big Query table in node.js (v12.15.0) using the table.delete() function from the google client library (linked below).

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#delete

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

async function deleteTable(
  datasetId = 'my_dataset',
  tableId = 'my_table',
) {
  console.log(`Deleting table ${tableId}`);
  try {
    const [table] = await bigquery
    .dataset(datasetId)
    .table(tableId)
    .delete();
    console.log(`Table ${tableId} deleted.`);
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}

deleteTable();
```

To run this, google needs authentication from your Big Query account, which I've downloaded as a json file and stored in a 'credentials' folder. The path is saved in my ~/.bash_profile as an environment variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/credentials/google_application_credentials.json"
```

When I try to run the above script, I get an ENOENT error:

```
Error: The file at {[contents of google_application_credentials.json]} does not exist, or it is not a file. 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/{[contents of google_application_credentials.json]}
   at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1529:7)
    at GoogleAuth._getApplicationCredentialsFromFilePath (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:250:27)
    at GoogleAuth._tryGetApplicationCredentialsFromEnvironmentVariable (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:192:25)
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:130:33)
    at GoogleAuth.getClient (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:502:28)
    at GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:543:35)
    at BigQuery.makeAuthenticatedRequest (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:374:28)
    at BigQuery.request_ (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service.js:129:18)
    at BigQuery.request (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service.js:140:36)
    at Dataset.request_ (/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.js:231:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/tom/Desktop/work/test/{[contents of google_application_credentials.json]}
```

Clearly, this script is searching for the contents of the .json file, rather than the file itself, in /Users/tom/Desktop/work/test, but I don't know why.
The path in the bash profile is definitely correct, and the environment variables are correctly updated.
If anyone could give me a hand, I'd be v grateful!
Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: There is a dot at the end of your *export* line. Why is that?

Comment: ah sorry, that was a mistake when I typed out the question - it's not in my bash_profile. I'll edit it out now.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
I restarted my laptop, which must have cleared out some environment variables that shouldn't have been there, and then downloaded a new .json file with the account authentication details from Big Query. Notably these had changed (I think they change with each download), so I could have been using an outdated file beforehand.

This made the script work as it should have.

If anyone has a better answer for what was actually going on, please do answer!